# Grabbing the name of the class just 1 up before the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I grab the name of the class that encases my select boxes using jQuery?

I've tried the following to no avail, thinking it would work, the answer should be alert("select_wrapper")

```
$('#content select').focus(function(e){

var eClass = $(e).get(0).attr('class')//$(e).attr('class')   

alert(eClass)

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="select_wrapper">
        <select id="profession">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>administrator</option>
            <option>web developer</option>
            <option>graphic artist</option>
            <option>IT professional</option>
            <option>other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#content select').focus(function(){
    var eClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    alert(eClass);
});
```

This gets the parent and outputs the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent element using method [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) of `$(this)`, and then you can use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to grab class name

```
$('#content select').focus(function (e) {
    var eClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    alert(eClass)
});
```

In your code `e` is event

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `jQuery` methods inside the function for this kind of task, just use (efficient) “vanilla JS”

```
$('#content select').focus(function(e){
   var eClass = this.parentNode.className;
   alert(eClass)
});
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEmIB

Answer (score 0):

You are using `e` as jQuery selector, but it is no the element, it is the event. You should try using `this`.

Then, to select the parent, jquery has the `.parent()` method.

Then you can get the class with `.attr()`:

```
var eClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
```

But you could not use jquery and go vanilla js. It is not complicated :

```
var eClass = this.parentNode.className;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#content select').focus(function(e){

    var eClass = $(this).parent().attr('class'); 

    alert(eClass)

});
```